# Render pop-up window doesnt show up

Tags: rendering, export

First of all, sorry for the bad English.
My problem is, that when I start the rendering (no matter if I start it with F12 or over the button at the top) the render pop-up window doesn't show up. At the bottom of the screen, there is a blue bar that fills up over time like it would render something but if I look in the folder with my rendered images there are only old renders.

I have tried to render another file but that doesn't show up as well. Do I need to reinstall Blender? and if I do so, are my files still working then?

Comment: Hello Elia :). You don't need to reinstall Blender, you probably just disabled the Render Window. Also, Blender doesn't export still-image renders automatically - only animations.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer :D
and how do I enable it again?

Comment: The linked answer should help :). Choose *Render in > New Window* in Preferences